# Cannot see samba shares on Ubuntu 16.04.4 from Windows 8.1 or 10

Tags: samba

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#0) as well as several other places to set up samba shares on Ubuntu 16.04.4. But no matter what I try, I cannot see these shares from either of my Windows computers (8.1 and 10). I've tried adding a mapped network drive to the path, browsing directly to it in the file explorer, nothing works.

Here's the output of a couple commands I've been using to check things on Ubuntu:

```
media@media-pc:~$ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[4TBshare]"
Processing section "[sambashare]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 enp3s0
        bind interfaces only = Yes
        server role = standalone server
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[4TBshare]
        comment = 4TB share on media-pc
        path = /mnt/4TB
        read only = No


[sambashare]
        comment = test share
        path = /home/media/sambashare
        read only = No

media@media-pc:~$ smbtree
Enter media's password:
WORKGROUP
        \\MEDIA-PC                      media-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu)
```

The smbtree output concerns me because it doesn't show any of the shares that I've set up. I tried sharing the folders directly from the file explorer GUI, that didn't change anything, either.

The shares show correctly, however, with smbclient:

```
media@media-pc:~$ smbclient -L 127.0.0.1
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter media's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

        Sharename       Type      Comment
        ---------       ----      -------
        print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
        4TBshare        Disk      4TB share on media-pc
        sambashare      Disk      test share
        IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (media-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu))
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

        Server               Comment
        ---------            -------
        MEDIA-PC             media-pc server (Samba, Ubuntu)

        Workgroup            Master
        ---------            -------
        WORKGROUP            MEDIA-PC
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out what the issue was. On Windows 10, I clicked on the diagnose button when it failed to map the network drive and it mentioned that it could talk to the remote server but it wouldn't respond. Looked into it, and it turned out that I needed to open up the ports in Ubuntu. Samba uses ports 139 and 445 for TCP and 137 and 138 for UDP. Opening those up with `ufw allow <port>` worked.